# Display users with relations in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display all my users with relations. Currently I have:

FilterController.php

```
public function getFilter($sport)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $users = $this->model->getUsersByDiscipline($sport);

        return view('filter.' . $sport, compact('user', 'users'));
    }
```

User.php

```
public function getUsersByDiscipline($sport)
    {
        $users = User::with('user_data', 'languages')->where('discipline', $sport)->get();

        return $users;
    }
```

And I try to display it like:

```
{{$user->user_data->employment}}
```

But there's error:

```
Property [employment] does not exist on this collection instance
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: can you paste blade view here? it seems you are not using foreach properly

Comment: Where is your loop?

Comment: is `employment` a relationship or an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

If `employment` is a relationship, I think it's not loaded yet. So you may load using nested eager loading.

In your eloquent query, you can use this:

```
$users = User::with('user_data.employment', 'languages')->where('discipline', $sport)->get();
```

Notice the dot syntax meaning `employment` is a relationship of `user_data`, it will now be loaded and accessible through: `$user->user_data->employment`

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading

Answer (score -1):

```
$users = User::with('user_data', 'languages')->where('discipline', $sport)->get();
```

by doing this you will get the array of $users

so you need to run a loop

```
@foreach($users as $user)
   {{ $user->user_data()->employment }}
@endforeach
```

Or you can debug a code in control

```
    $users = User::with('user_data', 'languages')->where('discipline', $sport)->get();

    foreach($users as $user){
       dd($user->user_data()); //check what it returns in user_data;
   }
```

Comment: By {{ $user->user_data()->short_description }} i got: 
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$short_description (View: /var/www/html/SCE/resources/views/filter/football.blade.php)
because I want to get short_description

Comment: this is wrong, `user_data()` should only be `user_data`, since we want to retrieve the relative **model**, `user_data()` returns a relation.

Comment: ohhh sorry then you can check for dd($user->user_data) what this statement return.